# `date` formatting to specifically add dots between the AM and PM markers

Tags: bash, shell, date

I use a command quite frequently called `datey` that I run by invoking `./datey` which will generate this date: "09/15/14 — 03:42:37 AM".  Nothing special, a very simple one line command.

I have always wanted the output to be slightly different, but have been unable to make that happen.  The command I am calling underneath all this is: `date`.  In it's simplest form, it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
date "+%D — %r"
```

Which results in:

```
09/15/14 — 03:45:45 AM
```

What I want:

```
09/15/14 — 03:45:55 A.M.
```

Or:

```
09/15/14 — 03:46:23 P.M.
```

Basically, just adding in dots in the A.M. and P.M. portion of the output. I am not sure if there is a standard, but to me, in the US, using dots is sort of a convention, that, at least in my geographic region, using dots.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed to make a little transform

```
# date "+%D - %r"|sed s/M/.M./g
09/15/14 - 12:53:10 P.M.
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly, it is what I have been trying to do for the past 15 minutes, but could not get sed to play nice.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `sed` on date's output:

```
date "+%D — %r" | sed 's/\([AP]\)\(M\)/\1.\2./'
09/15/14 — 06:53:42 A.M.
```

Comment: Or better yet `d=$(date '+%D - %r'); echo "${d%M}.M."`

Comment: @fedorqui: My apologies, I didn't notice that. Rolled back now.

Comment: No problem at all, I know you did it by good :) +1 again for both solutions!

Comment: triplee, I just ran that, it is 3 minutes before midnight, the results I get are not correct: 09/15/14 - 11:59:34 P.M. also, why do you set to var $d but also echo, can I remove the d= part? Any idea why the P.M. is happening prior to it being P.M.

Comment: anubhava, your method seems to work perfect, though I won't know for sure until 12 hours from now when I can test it for real.  Thank you!

Comment: I would like to close in saying this does in fact work, I am going to mark a different answer as correct because it is slightly more concise and easier to understand in my personal opinion.  They both work, both use the same "logic" and are probably equally efficient for something so small and simple.  Thank you!

Comment: Sure that is your prerogative. But you need to be careful with that answer if you ever change date format to something like this: `date "+%a, %D - %r"`. That date command might give you a date as this: `Mon, 09/15/14 - 03:24:20 AM'` and using other `sed` it will become: `.M.on, 09/15/14 - 03:24:20 A.M.`.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the trailing `M` and add `.M.` to the end of the string:

```
$ d=$(date "+%D — %r")
$ echo "${d%M}.M."
09/15/14 — 07:25:14 A.M.
```

Comment: This is the same as Raul Andres answer, though he included the actual `date` command in his example. For the sake of the user who is copying and pasting, I have up voted you, but marked Raul Andres as the correct answer.  Thank you both.

Comment: @Scott Close, but not the same as his `sed` does a global replacement of any `M` where mine removes the trailing `M` from the string and appends it with `.M.`  The equivalent `sed` would be `date "+%D — %r"|sed 's/M$/.M./'`.